# Perguntas sobre mermaid são no tópico?

Tags: suporte, escopo-do-site

Acabei de ver uma [pergunta relativamente bem aceita sobre fluxograma em LaTeX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180183/64969). Então, fiquei na dúvida: *será que perguntas sobre mermaid também são no tópico?*

Para quem não conhece, mermaid é uma ferramenta JS que interpreta uma descrição de um grafo e o plota na tela. [Site oficial](https://mermaidjs.github.io/), [*live editor*](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/).

Pergunto isso porque estou começando a usá-lo para fazer documentação de software, então suspeito que possa ser no tópico, assim como o LaTeX.

Comment: Não vejo porque não seria. Não só é dentro como fica "lá no meião". _"This is why mermaid was born, a simple markdown-like script language for generating charts from text via javascript"_

Comment: @Bacco não vejo porque não sereia

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tivemos a mermaidéia, mas você foi mais rápido pra postar.

Comment: Tudo serve para um Brasileiro fazer uma piada :D

Comment: Não conhecia essa ferramenta JS, e como já cliquei no link da pergunta primeiro, fique viajando pensando *"o que 'sereias' tem a ver com LaTeX"*? :P